# How to handle a bunch of nested ValueObjects?

Tags: design-patterns, php, constructors, factory-pattern

I'm writing a PHP web application (or actually a Symfony module). One part of it is a nested structure of `ValueObject`s (meaning: they are immutable and have to be validated on the creating). Such an object can have about ten plain properties and sometimes a couple of further `DataObject` properties.

Semantics: The classes **represent** the requests and responses of the [Klarna Payments API](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#payments-api).

The `*Request` objects are **used** to pass the data to the `PaymentService`, that needs it to send it to Klarna. The `*Response` objects are used for encapsulating the Klarna reponses.

The original data **source** for `*Request` objects can be the user session or an incoming call of another internal application (a shop system), that deals with the order processing (e.g. the shop notifies the payment module about a successful shipping and triggers so a capture request towards Klarna). The data source for `*Response` objects are typically the Klarna responses.

<strike>Currently the objects provide **long constructors**, that get a structured array data passed in and convert / map it to their plain properties and the nested objects (s. example below).</strike>

Currently the objects provide **long constructors**, that get a bunch of plain variables and (sometimes nested) objects passed in (s. example below).

Problems:

1. The client of the service needs to **know** the complete structure of the `*Request` objects,  that are actually more intended for the internal / payment module internal usage.
2. <strike>Dealing with arrays as data transfer format (at least partially).</strike> (became obsolete due to some refactoring.)
3. The **instantiating** bloats the code.
4. The instance, which needs the object (e.g. for returning it a call response) is the instance, that have the data need for building this object.

**How to refactor this to a more elegant solution? What design pattern might be suitable?**

Some thoughts...

Factory Method? If so, should the `Factory` retrieve the data itself (e.g. from the session, the database etc.)? Or maybe a Simple Factory, that gets the type of the needed `Request|Response` passed to the `create(...)`?

**UPDATE**

The problem with the Factory Method pattern is the following: In my humble opinion a good factory should not force its client to provide the stuff need for creating an object -- it's the job of the factory. At the same time in my case sometimes it's possible (e.g., when the data for creation can be retrieved from the cache or the database) -- but sometimes the client itself has the data (e.g. as response of an  outgoing API call or data coming in through a web callback). Meaning: some factories would look "healthy" and other ones would look like this:

```
class MyFooResponseFactory extends ResponseFactory
{
    public create(array $data) {...}
}
```

Builder? No, for the following reason:

The more I'm thinking about this problem the more I'm reasoning, that the core problem here is the fact, that the client is (or at least sometimes can be) the instance, that should be the client of the factory or the builder, whatever, *is* the instance, that provides the data for the result object, I want to build. And it's a neither the Builder, nor the Factory pattern can help here.

<strike>It's `ValueObject`s. So they should not provide any setters. So the Builder pattern cannot be applied here; at least no classical / straight forward implementation will be possible. (Or they need to become "normal" `DataObject`s.)</strike> Update: It's not a valid argument against the Builder pattern, since the Builder can first gather the data and then apply it once it instantiates the result object internally. So the builder's setters don't need to match to or call the object's setters.

---

**Example**, how it's implemented now:

**`DataObject`s**:

```
class KlarnaCreateSessionRequest
{
    public function __construct(
        string $acquiringChannel,
        KlarnaAttachment $attachment,
        KlarnaAddress $billingAddress,
        string $clientRoken,
        array $customPaymentMethodIds,
        KlarnaCustomer $customer,
        string $design,
        string $expiresAt,
        string $locale,
        string $merchant_data,
        string $merchant_reference1,
        string $merchant_reference2,
        KlarnaMerchantUrls $merchant_urls,
        KlarnaOptions $options,
        string $orderAmount,
        KlarnaOrderLines $orderLines,
        string $orderTaxAmount,
        KlarnaPaymentMethodCategories $paymentMethodCategories,
        string $purchaseCountry,
        string $purchaseCurrency,
        KlarnaAddress $shippingAddress,
        string $status
    ) {
        // assignments
        // ...
        // validation
        // ...
        if(! $dataIsValid) {
            throw new DataNotValidException('...');
        }
    }
}
class KlarnaAttachment {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaAddress {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaCustomer {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaMerchantUrls {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaOptions {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaOrderLines {
    // ...
}
class KlarnaPaymentMethodCategories {
    // ...
}
```

**`KlarnaPaymentService`**, where the data is actually needed:

```
class KlarnaPaymentService
{
    public function createSession(KlarnaCreateSessionRequest $klarnaCreateSessionRequest): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**`KlarnaPaymentProcessor`**, that gathers the data, builds a complete nested request object, and passes it to the service:

```
class KlarnaPaymentProcessor
{
    // properties
    // constructor
    // ...
    public function startPayment(): void
    {
        $this->klarnaPaymentService->createSession(
            $this->createKlarnaCreateSessionRequest()
        );
    }

    private function createKlarnaCreateSessionRequest(): array
    {
        // ... Some stuff to get the create session request data from the user session and/or other places.
        return new KlarnaCreateSessionRequest(
            'ecommerce',
            new KlaAttachment(
                '{"customer_account_info":[{"unique_account_identifier":"test@gmail.com","account_registration_date":"2017-02-13T10:49:20Z","account_last_modified":"2019-03-13T11:45:27Z"}]}',
                'application/vnd.klarna.internal.emd-v2+json'
            ),
            'string',
            new KlarnaAddress(
                'Attn',
                'London',
                'GB',
                'test.sam@test.com',
                'Andersson',
                'Adam',
                'string',
                '+44795465131',
                'W1G 0PW',
                'OH',
                '33 Cavendish Square',
                'Floor 22 / Flat 2',
                'Mr.'
            ),
            'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ewogICJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIiA6ICIw',
            [
                0 => 'string',
            ],
            new KlarnaCustomer(
                '1978-12-31',
                'male',
                'string',
                'string',
                'LIMITED_COMPANY',
                'string',
                'Mr.',
                'organization',
                'string'
            ),
            'string',
            '2038-01-19T03:14:07.000Z',
            'en-GB',
            '{"order_speicif":[{"substore":"Women\'s Fashion","product_name":"Women Sweatshirt"}]}',
            'ON4711',
            'hdt53h-zdgg6-hdaff2',
            new KlarnamerchantUrls(
                'https://...',
                'https://...',
                'https://...'
            ),
            new KlarnaOptions(
                '#FF9900',
                '#FF9900',
                '#FF9900',
                '#FF9900',
                '5px'
            ),
            2500,
            new KlarnaOrderLines([
                0 => new KlarnaOrderLine(
                    'https://www.exampleobjects.com/logo.png',
                    '{"customer_account_info":[{"unique_account_identifier":"test@gmail.com","account_registration_date":"2017-02-13T10:49:20Z","account_last_modified":"2019-03-13T11:45:27Z"}]}',
                    'Running shoe',
                    new KlarnaProductIndentifiers(
                        'shoe-brand',
                        'Shoes > Running',
                        '4912345678904',
                        'AD6654412-334.22'
                    ),
                    'https://.../AD6654412.html',
                    1,
                    'pcs',
                    'AD6654412',
                    1900,
                    2500,
                    500,
                    475,
                    'physical',
                    2500
                ),
            ]),
            475,
            new KlarnaPaymentMethodCategories([
                0 => new KlarnaPaymentMethodCategory(
                    new KlarnaAssetUrls(
                        'https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg',
                        'https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg',
                    ),
                    'pay_later',
                    'Pay Later'
                ),
            ]),
            'GB',
            'GBP',
            new KlarnaAddress(
                'Attn',
                'London',
                'GB',
                'test.sam@test.com',
                'Andersson',
                'Adam',
                'string',
                '+44795465131',
                'W1G 0PW',
                'OH',
                '33 Cavendish Square',
                'Floor 22 / Flat 2',
                'Mr.'
            ),
            'complete'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: *'Currently the objects provide long constructors, that get a structured array data passed in and convert / map it to their plain properties and the nested objects.'* Could you clarify this? Maybe a code example?

Comment: @RikD Thank you for your comment. Just updated the question with a code example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you decompose a constructor?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231915/how-can-you-decompose-a-constructor)

Comment: It will sound controverting but I don't care. I think the `Builder` pattern is the way to go. For (at least) 2 reasons: #1 you can hide the needs of `KlarnaCreateSessionRequest` for countless dependencies, #2 the builder can be passed as an argument to different components so each component fills the data it knows.  I got the feeling your main concerns are #1 and #3 and I agree. None of the two is addressable with factories. Bundling arguments will solve (in the best of the cases) only #3 and only partially.

Comment: The KlarnaCreateSessionRequest class looks like it has lots of constructor arguments that should be related, but it is difficult to tease out how. I think that is the biggest code smell to sort out, and will likely lead you to a solution. How are these constructor arguments related?

Comment: There is a `billingAddress` and `shippingAddress`. It really feels like those are related. What "thing" do they belong to? They should belong to something, and not just be floating around in their own pools.

Comment: @GregBurghardt thanks for you comment. I read the question "How can you decompose a constructor?" and also the solutions and some links continuative links (e.g. to related questions). But no, IMO the question is pointing another problem and also the solutions don't solve my current issue. Please see the **UPDATE** to the question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt To the addresses: They are both addresses and have from the same type `Address`.

Comment: @GregBurghardt "_ lots of constructor arguments that should be related, but it is difficult to tease out how [...] is the biggest code smell to sort out_" I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly. But if yes, it's still about decomposition and the Builder pattern. But actually would like to let the objects and their structure as they are. Sins it matches to the Klarna requests and response, which is handy. And another point: I think now, that real problem (and the solution) lays not in the objects, but in the fact, that the client is the source of data for the creating. S. question update.

Comment: *”The instance, which needs the object (e.g. for returning it a call response) is the instance, that have the data need for building this object.”* can you elaborate on this? I am having difficulty in understanding it.

Comment: I believe @GregBurghardt is pointing you to the direction I'd also point: identify what's called "data clumps" and give them a place; a name (type). I'd also suggest that you create VOs for all other properties. This way you don't have to rely on the variable name to distinguish between `$design` and `$expiresAt` strings, for example. Expanding on the `Address` example, even though they are both "addresses", you can go another level up in your abstraction and have `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` types as they seem to speak closer to your domain language.

Comment: One way you can try and tackle this is to start at the end: contemplate what would be the ideal interface, and then work back from there to figure out what changes you'd need to make to get there. But, given what you've said so far, I think all you really need to do at this point is to refactor all these data structure parameters into separate private methods to get: `new KlarnaCreateSessionRequest('ecommerce', extractKlaAttachment(), 'string', extractBillingAddress(), ...`